# Cassandra Order By Updated At

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to build a cassandra schema to represent chat.
The one thing i can't seem to figure out is how to query most recently updated rooms (similar to most chat app list view)

- Fields desired in list view ordered by `updated_at` desc

  - *room id
  - room title
  - room image
  - *user
  - *updated_at
  - *message entry
  - *message type
  - *metadata

**Current Tables**

```
Create TYPE user(
   id uuid,
   name text,
   avatar text
);

CREATE TABLE rooms(
  id uuid,
  "name" text,
  image text,
  users set<user>,
  archived boolean,
  created_at timestampz,
  updated_at timestampz,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE TABLE messages(
  room_id uuid,
  message_id timeuuid,
  user user,
  message_type int,
  entry text,
  metadata map<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY(room_id, message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);


CREATE TABLE rooms_by_user(
  user_id uuid,
  room_id uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, room_id)
);
```

Possible solutions that i can come up with.

- Duplicate all room details to each message

  - allows easy query with `SELECT * FROM messages PER PARTITION LIMIT 1`
  - this would be a lot of duplicate data per message...
- Query latest messages which user belongs to get room ids then query rooms

  - This doesn't seem to be the cassandra way?

Is there a better way to model my data?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the schema it looks like you need relational database.

In Cassandra usually you use `one table per query`, it means you you should design your table by how you will structure query.

Also you can query by `partition key` or `clustering column` (second one should be `partition key + clustering column`).
So in order to query by `updater_at`, you need to make that column as clustering column. And keep in mind that in Cassandra you cannot alter keys.

Comment: yeah, there is materialized views i could use for the altering updated at. also please read the rest of the post... if you could also elaborate more otherwise this answer doesn't really help anyone...

Comment: materialized views are not production ready.

Comment: @jklaw90 Hey, I understood what you are saying, I proposed you to make `updated_at` as clustering column so you can sort it and query by the value.